# Why does strlen() apply on character arrays also?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

strlen() is a function argument should be a string but why is it also applicable to character arays ?
For eg

```
char abc[100];   
cin.getline(abc,100);  
len=strlen(abc);
```

If it works for character array and tells the number of elements , can it be used for int array also?

Note : I am using TurboC++

Comment: It *only* works for `char` arrays. It doesn't work for C++ strings.

Comment: @Brian It comes under string.h header file . So if it was for char arrays , why is it placed there . (just asking out of curiousity , thanks for the reply btw )

Comment: Because strings (specifically C-style strings, *not* C++-style `std::string`s) are stored in character arrays.

Comment: @KeithThompson But my question was solely based on C++ . Maybe as MikeSeymour said , C-style strings can be used in C++ , so its in string.h

Comment: C++ supports C-style strings, and `<string.h>` (or `<cstring>`) operates on C-style strings. Not to be confused with the C++-specific type `std::string`, defined in the `<string>` (no `.h`) header.

Comment: @KeithThompson Okay . Now I get it . Thanks

Comment: I've also updated my answer; see the first 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to understand what a *string* is. The C standard defines a *string* as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". It's a data *format*, not a data *type*; a C-style string may be contained in an array of `char`.  This is not to be confused with the C++-specific type `std::string`, defined in the `<string>` (note: no `.h` suffix) header.

The `<string.h>` header, or preferably the `<cstring>` header, is incorporated into C++ from the C standard library. The functions declared in that header operate on C-style strings, or on pointers to them.

The argument to `strlen` is of type `char*`, a pointer to a character. (It's actually `const char*`, meaning that `strlen` promises not to modify whatever it points to.)

An array expression is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the initial element of the array. (See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) for the details.)

The `char*` argument that you pass to `strlen` *must* point to the initial element of an array of characters, and there must be a null character (`'\0'`) somewhere in the array to mark the end of the string. It computes the number of characters up to, but not including, the null terminator.

It does not (and cannot) compute the number of elements in an array, only the number of characters in a string -- which it can do only if the array actually contains a valid string. If there is no null character anywhere in the array, or if the pointer is null or otherwise invalid, the behavior is undefined.

So when you write:

```
char abc[100];
cin.getline(abc,100);
len=strlen(abc);
```

the call to `cin.getline` ensures that the array `abc` contains a properly null-terminated string. `strlen(abc)` calls `strlen`, passing it the address of the initial character; it's equivalent to `strlen(&abc[0])`.

No, `strlen` will not work on an array of `int`. For one thing, that would pass an `int*` value, which doesn't match the `char*` that `strlen` requires, so it probably wouldn't compile. Even ignoring that, `strlen` counts characters, not `int`s. (You can write your own similar function that counts `int`s if you like, but it still has to have some way to find the end of the elements that you're interested in counting. It doesn't have access to the actual length of the array unless you pass it explicitly.)

Comment: Excellent . I think _Detailization of an answer is directly proportional to the reputation of the answerer_ .

Comment: @eatq: In other words, the more time I spend here, the worse I get at writing short answers. 8-)}

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` only works for **null-terminated** char arrays.

If there's no null character at the end of the string<sup>1</sup>, calling `strlen` causes undefined behavior.

`std::cin.getline` automatically appends the null character at the end so that's why your `strlen` worked.

<sup>1 (which is not necessarily the same as the end of the array)</sup>

Comment: Your last sentence is somewhat imprecise; the null character may appear before the actual end of the string, and it wouldn't be UB.

Comment: Thanks . So here   cin.getline() adds a null at the end automatically ?

Comment: @black Yes I meant the end of the string, not the end of the array necessarily. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In C strings are arrays of `char`. All strlen does is count the number of items until a 0 (or null character) is found

Comment: its valid for c++ also right ? You mentioned C while I am working on C++ .

Comment: @eatq: You can use C-style strings (with the C library) in C++, if you're feeling masochistic. You might find the C++ `std::string` easier to use.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Masochistic maybe, but nothing teaches pointers faster =)